# Stochastic forces, their relation to Probability and active matter

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, stochastic-processes

Recently, I've been trying to read up a lot on active matter, and I realize most of what I read are papers that are relatively new. But to dive into the topic as well, I am unable to find much backing with the theory taught to us in classes. Can anybody give me some solid references to start properly in this field?

Comment: What kind of background do you have already (e.g., undergrad, grad? In physics, math, etc)?

Comment: @KyleKanos i am graduate student in physics with a mathematics minor. I've had all the basic courses in physics - classical mechanics, quantum mechanics, classical field theory, statistical mechanics and so on.